# Error writing cfimage as a base64 on production but not on development server

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, cfimage

I have a process that read and image, resizes it and writes base64 version of the image to a text file.  It is working on a development box but when this code is moved to a production server I am getting an error stating that the image doesn't contain the function writeBase64. The image is "dumping" correctly (as seen below).

```
imageResize(getTube,'','50%');
writeDump(getTube);
lock timeout="1" scope="server" type="exclusive"{
    getTube.writeBase64('base64img/base64_1_#randrange(100,999)#.txt', 'png');
}
```

[image]

I thought it was possible that it was because the development server is newer version of Lucee than production.  But I get an error going to the "Update" page on the admin of the production server. 
[image]

That is a different post but I included it here in case there is some connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this I changed the Lucee jar file to Lucee 5.3.4.80 and it solved both issues